# How to write code documentation in Typo3 6.x?

Tags: typo3

We need to write a complex documentation of the API use in Typo3 6.x, but entering the code samples through RTE is very error-prone, and using just HTML element defeats the purpose of CMS.

Is there any way for nice (for editors) entering of text wrapped around code samples in various programming languages, for Typo3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative is to use the extensions restdoc (for display) and sphinx (for generation) to make use of `restructured text` to write the documentation the same way the documentation of `TYPO3` is created.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Markdown content elements. I've never tried it, but there is an extension for it (`markdown_content_reloaded`).

Comment: This is not a bad idea, but do you have any idea how to color the syntax of the embedded programming code?

Comment: You could use a JavaScript syntax highlighter, I used [SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/) once and it worked quite well. The remaining problem would be to detect the used language, if you have multiple languages. I believe in that case standard markdown wouldn't help (github flavoured markdown would), so you would have to set a class to the content element or similar. When you want to do this stuff server-side, you would probably have to cook up an extension yourself. Alternatively, you could try the extension [beautyOfCode](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/beautyofcode).